# React Native Flip Card default clickable false and make true on button click

Tags: react-native, flip

I am working on React Native Project, I am using [react-native-flip-card](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-flip-card) this component.

My requirement is to make clickable false on initial start and on click of button make clickable true for the flip cards.

Comment: So, correct me if i'm wrong, you want a Flipcard that is not clickable by default. But then if you press another button, make it clickable.
Is it right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case you want to modify a behaviour inside a Component, the [State Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) seems like the things you need.

You can set a state property such as :

```
this.state = {
  isClickable: false,
}
```

by default in your Component Constructor.

And then assign this value to your FlipCard component, such as :

```
<FlipCard 
 *Your other properties*
 clickable={this.state.isClickable}
>
```

Finally, just update your state property when another event such as a button click happens :

```
<Button
 onPress={() => this.setState({isClickable: true})}
 title="Make Flipcard clickable"
 color="#841584"
/>
```

That's it ! Do not hesitate to ask more question if something isn't clear enough.

Comment: Code is working for single flip card, but i need dynamic like one flipcard then one image, second filpcard then other image. I need to disable click on individual flipcards passing ids or something like that. Like when click on image then flipcard set to false again.

Comment: for example if you click on flipcard then set it "clickable" again to False.